# Replace characters in a table - ADA

Tags: ada, tabular

I created a table ( 62 x 35 ) with characters in the table. I'm trying to replace the characters in a 10 x 10 table from the middle by others.

For example, if I have a table that looks like that: (62 x 35)

```
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
############################################################## 
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
```

I want to be able to load a file containing (10x10):

```
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
```

so that the characters in this file replace the characters in the table created previously

i.e. have a table that looks like

```
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##########################//////////##########################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
```

I don't think what I'm trying to do is very clear, so if you want more details please ask.

```
procedure Grid_Pilliers(A: out Grid) is  -- creates grid with pilliers --
begin
   for I in 0..31 loop
      for J in 0..75 loop
         if (I mod 4 = 1 or I mod 4 = 0) and (J mod 4 = 1 or J mod 4 = 0) then
            A(I,J) := true ;
         else
            A(I,J) := false ;
         end if ;
      end loop ;
   end loop ;
end Grid_Pilliers ;


procedure New_Grid_Random_Fill(A : in out New_Grid) is

   type Numero is range 0 .. 1;
   package Grid_Random is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Numero);
   use Grid_Random;
   Random_Number : Numero;
   G : Generator;

begin
   Reset (G);
   for I in A'Range(1) loop
      for J in A'Range(2) loop
         Random_Number := Random (G);
         A(I,J) := (Random_Number = 1);
      end loop;
   end loop;
end New_Grid_Random_Fill;
```

Comment: I see no Ada question here.

Comment: Same for me. What is your question exactly ? Do you have difficulties in writing the algorithm ? Do you get an unclear compiler error message ? I think it would be easier to help if you could turn your problem description into a real question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach. See also [*Fixed-Length String Handling*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html).

Comment: I created both tables and I would like to put in the center  of the big table one the small one, and I don't know how to write that in Ada.

Comment: What does the code for your tables look like?

Comment: @Marc i've edited my post and put codes for both of my tables

Comment: @user1816067: Markdown requires 4-space indentation for code formatting; you had 3-space indentation for your tables. I've fixed it (and made the indentation for your code more consistent).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use slicing... but for this example I'll use a pair of for-loops.
Assuming you have the table-type (`Grid`) defined as `Array (Positive Range <>, Positive Range <>) of Character`...

```
procedure copy_into( Working : in out Grid; subimage : in Grid;
                     Offset_X, Offset_Y : Natural ) is
begin
 -- insert checks for subimage lengths [plus offsets]
 -- to be less than Working's lengths.

 for index_x in subimage'Range(1) loop
   for index_y in subimage'Range(2) loop
     Working(index_x+offset_x, index_y+offset_y):= subimage(index_x, index_y);
   end loop;
 end loop;
end copy_into;
```

To get the offsets is simple:

offset_x = big_grid_width + small_grid_width / 2.

offset_y = the above, but using height.

Comment: I disagree that slices should be used. I think it is probably better to use a two dimensional array and (therefore) nested loops. But I think this is a good answer, as far as the poster's intent can be discerned. In Ada 2012, the checks could be expressed as preconditions.